# Does boltdb support concurrent queries for reading and updating the db?

Tags: database, go, key-value-store, boltdb

Currently using `boltdb` for storing various entries in the bucket.

How can I use goroutines and channels in reading and updating in the db?

Comment: This is too broad a question - you should attempt to achieve your goal yourself and then when you hit specific problems ask for help overcoming those barriers.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, yes you can, provided you pay attention to the following points:

- all accesses should be done in their own transactions. Transactions should not be shared between goroutines (whether they are read-only or read-write).
- boltdb only tolerates one writer at a given point in time. If multiple concurrent transactions try to write at the same time, they will be serialized. The consistency of the database is guaranteed, but it has an impact on the performance, since write operations cannot be parallelized.
- read-only transactions are executed concurrently (and potentially parallelized).
- open only one transaction in a given goroutine at the same time to avoid deadlock situations.